# HQL query in oneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

We have two Entities, `Person` and `House`.

One `Person` can have Many `House`.

I'm trying to write an HQL query that get the list of `Person` ordered by the size of the list of `House`, with one condition, that the value of the `House` should be greater than `400`.

My class Person

```
@Entity
    public class Person{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = 
        "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<House> houses = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * utility method to adjust relation
     * @param house
     */
    public void addHouse( House house ) {
        this.houses.add(house);
        house.setPerson(this);
    }
       //constructors, getters and setter omitted..
    }
```

My class House

```
@Entity
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Integer value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

   //constructors, getters and setters omitted..
}
```

My tables representation on the database Layer

```
Person                     House
id name                    id   value  person_id
1  George                  1    500     1
2  Frederic                2    250     2
3  Jamal                   3    500     3
                           4    600     3
```

The result of my query should be [Jamal, George], and Frederic should not be included because the only house he has, doesn't have a value `>400`.

My query

```
public interface PersonRepository  extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

      @Query(value = "select p from Person p order by p.houses.size desc ")
      List<Person> getPersonWithMaxHouse();
}
```

with that, I'm getting an ordered list of persons based on the number of houses.
How could I add the condition of the value of the `House`.

My second question is about the Sprig Data JPA Query equivalent of the hql I'm looking?

For example this repository query return all the persons whose names is equal to the given String :  `List<Person> findAllByName(String Name);`

Comment: To your second question - JPA Is a Specification  , we can use their feature in ORM line Hibernate  , Try to use the link then you will get understand    https://what-when-how.com/hibernate/querying-with-hql-and-jpa-ql-hibernate/

Comment: My second question is about using the Spring Repositories Queries like : List<Person> findAllByName(String Name);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
public interface PersonRepository  extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

      @Query(value = "select distinct p from Person p join p.houses h where h.value > 400 order by p.houses.size desc ")
      List<Person> getPersonWithMaxHouse();
}
```